# multiple fisher test on row of dataframe

Tags: r, statistics

I am a begeinner in R and would like to make multiple fisher tests on mutiple row of a dataframe and add the p value/odd ratio on a barplot but need some help.

Here are my data

```
data=data.frame(Liste=c("List1", "List2", "List3", "List4"), 
               TPA=c(9,8,25,3), 
               TPB=c(7,18,14,12))

data=data %>% mutate (tot=TPA+TPB)

   Liste TPA TPB tot
1 List1   9   7  16
2 List2   8  18  26
3 List3  25  14  39
4 List4   3  12  15
```

In order to make the barblot I reshape a little bit my data like this

```
tab14=melt(as.data.table(data), id.vars = c("Liste", "tot") )
tab15= tab14 %>% mutate(pct=value/tot*100)

  Liste tot variable value      pct
1: List1  16      TPA     9 56.25000
2: List2  26      TPA     8 30.76923
3: List3  39      TPA    25 64.10256
4: List4  15      TPA     3 20.00000
5: List1  16      TPB     7 43.75000
6: List2  26      TPB    18 69.23077
7: List3  39      TPB    14 35.89744
8: List4  15      TPB    12 80.00000

ggplot(tab15, aes(x=Liste, y=pct, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position="dodge")
```

Now I would like to make fisher test between TPA and TPB for each list, and then between the different lists.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arKbd.png)

I could do it making the contingency table one by one and by adding the p value manually by editing my figure but I don't know how to do it automatically with R.

```
tab_cont_List1vsList2=data %>%  filter((Liste=="List1" |Liste=="List2" )) %>% select( -Liste,-tot)

  TPA TPB
1   9   7
2   8  18

test=fisher.test(tab_cont_List1vsList2)
p2=test$p.value
```

I am open to any suggestions to help me.

Comment: can you specify what exactly you want to test? is it all 6 possible combinations of list1 : list 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, get the combinations:

```
idx = t(combn(seq_along(data$Liste),2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    2    3
[5,]    2    4
[6,]    3    4
```

Then:

```
res = lapply(1:nrow(idx),function(i){
      test = fisher.test(data[idx[i,],c("TPA","TPB")])
      data.frame(
         list1 = data$Liste[idx[i,1]],
         list2 = data$Liste[idx[i,2]],
         odds_ratio = as.numeric(test$estimate),
         p = as.numeric(test$p.value)
     )
})

res = do.call(rbind,res)
res

  list1 list2 odds_ratio           p
1 List1 List2  2.8162459 0.120542971
2 List1 List3  0.7244134 0.760816253
3 List1 List4  4.8573292 0.065892860
4 List2 List3  0.2546791 0.011637052
5 List2 List4  1.7538485 0.715806992
6 List3 List4  6.8725049 0.005673158
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good idea, but it would be better for me to have no duplicated test (ex: list1 vs list4 and list4 vs list1). I will try to think another way to do that.

Comment: I can add a base R solution.. my tidyverse sux

Comment: Sound much better. Thanks a lot. Would you also have an idea on the way to plot the value on the boxplot.

Comment: Hi that's another question altogether. Please post it as a separate question.